# GDB PEMicro interface debugging not showing up

Tags: gdb, microcontroller, nxp-microcontroller

I recently installed Kinetis Deign Studio 3.2.0 on Mac OSX High Sierra and am I trying to flash a FRDM-KL26Z (am studying this at the University and everybody use Windows, unfortunatly).
I installed the GDB PEMicro packs, but the problem is that the only configuration that shows up into the Flash Configurations is GDB Segger J-Link Debugging. 
I've tried to select and deselect several options from Launch Configurations, without succes; the only thing that changes is J-Link dissapearing from Flash Configurations.
Any help, or suggestions?

[image]